# Cut rows if column D is not null and paste in a specific place in the same sheet based on contents in column C

Tags: vba, excel

I have never worked in VBA before and have only used Excel for the basics.  I am trying to make a script that can be used to interact with several hundred different spreadsheets all of the same format.  Other items exist in the spread sheets, but my task is to take 2 numbered lists, one of process steps, and one of expected results and put a * in front of process step numbers and + in front of the expected results numbers.  In cases where the expected result text is not blank I need to insert that row under the coresponding number in the process steps list.  The first list always starts on row 25 and the second always starts two rows under where the first list ends both are numbered in column C with the text in column D and may be of varying lengths.  Column D in expected results is more often than not blank.  Also there is a 3rd list under expected results in column C and D, but it is to be left alone.  Any help would be appreciated.

This puts the * and + on reliably I have tried a bunch of stuff but have nothing worth showing to select and move the lines.

```
Sub StepOrderTest()
'
' StepOrderTest Macro
' First attempt to record Step Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("C25").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "*1"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range([C25], [C25].End(xlDown)),      Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range([C25], [C25].End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
    Range(Selection).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "+1"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)),    Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
End Sub
```

Essentially I am trying to make a script that will change this.

```
Process Steps List

    1   Step1
    2   Step2
    3   Step3
    4   Step4
    5   Step5
    6   Step6
    7   Step7
    8   Step8
    9   Step9
    10  Step10
    11  Step11
    12  Step12
    13  Step13
    14  Step14
    15  Step15

Expected Results            
    1   

    2   

    3   Expected ResultA

    4   

    5   

    6   

    7   Expected ResultB

    8   

    9   

    10  

    11  

    12  Expected ResultC

    13  

    14  

    15  Expected ResultD

To something like this.
    Process Steps List          
    *1  Step1
    *2  Step2
    *3  Step3
    +3  Expected ResultA
    *4  Step4
    *5  Step5
    *6  Step6
    *7  Step7
    +7  Expected ResultB
    *8  Step8
    *9  Step9
    *10 Step10
    *11 Step11
    *12 Step12
    +12 Expected ResultC
    *13 Step13
    *14 Step14
    *15 Step15
    +15 Expected ResultD
```

Comment: Just a suggestion:  Try explaining what you are trying to do in Outline form.  Include pseudo-code for IF statements.  When you see it laid out in outline form it becomes easier to create code for each item..  Paragraphs tend to lead to thinking "I want this result" when really there are several results combined for the ultimate result.  Break it down into small steps.

Comment: Thanks peege! I just added something to make it a bit clearer.  I believe the end result of this is to have someone go through all 900 or so of these worksheets apply the script and cut and past the updated process steps list out to a paragraph area in test track.  It really is a simple thing to do manually but I have had no luck figuring out how to make it go through the second list and find the items without going into the (not pictured) 3rd list and then place them correctly in the first list.

Comment: can you take screenshots of your sheets, and show layout?

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks weird. Anyway, the code below will do what I guess you pretend, as long as "Process Step List" data are in columns `A` and `B`, and "Expected results" in columns `D` and `E`. The desired output will be in columns `G` and `H`. All this in a Worksheet named "Sheet1". Modify at your convenience.

```
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim i, a As Integer
Dim sProcStep As Integer
Dim Lookup_Range As Range

Sub sss()

lLastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row 'assuming "Process Step List" is in columns A and B, starting from second row
Set Lookup_Range = Range("D:E") 'assuming "Expected Results" are in columns D and E
a = 2

For i = 2 To lLastRow
    sProcStep = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
    ExpResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sProcStep, Lookup_Range, 2, False)
    If ExpResult = "" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(a, 7) = "*" & sProcStep
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(a, 8) = "*" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
        a = a + 1
    Else
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(a, 7) = "*" & sProcStep
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(a, 8) = "*" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
        a = a + 1
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(a, 7) = "'+" & sProcStep
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(a, 8) = ExpResult
        a = a + 1
    End If
Next
End Sub
```